# How can I merge rows in a dataframe that have both numeric and character observations

Tags: r, merge, character, aggregate

I have a dataset that has multiple ID's in common, I want to merge the rows that these where the ID and Collection date match and fill in any NA values with existing results.  Anything that is NA for both occurrences should remain as NA.

```
ID <- c(1,2,1,2)
COLLECTION_DT <- c(2016-07-01, 2016,08-09, 2016-07-01, 2016-08-09)
TEST1 <- c(Negative, 100, NA, NA)
TEST2 <- c(Positive, NA, NA, Negative)
TEST3 <- c(NA, Negative, Negative, NA)
```

```
ID   COLLECTION_DT  TEST1      TEST2       TEST.3
1    2016-07-01     Negative   Positive    NA
2    2016-08-09     100        NA          NA
1    2016-07-01     NA         NA          Negative
2    2016-08-09     NA         Negative    NA
```

I have tried this but the rows are filled with NA's

```
Total.1 <- aggregate(Total[-(1:2)], Total[c("ID", "COLLECTION_DT")], 
          function(x) max(as.character(x)))
```

I want it to look like this

```
ID   COLLECTION_DT  TEST1      TEST2       TEST.3
1    2016-07-01     Negative   Positive    Negative
2    2016-08-09     100        Negative    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you posted and the data print out are slightly different for `TEST.3` so I adjusted your example data slightly, but the following is one option that I believe does what you are after, by using `dplyr::group_by` and `na.omit`:

```
ID <- c(1,2,1,2)
COLLECTION_DT <- as.Date(c('2016-07-01', '2016-08-09', '2016-07-01', '2016-08-09'))
TEST1 <- c('Negative', 100, NA, NA)
TEST2 <- c('Positive', NA, NA, 'Negative')
TEST3 <- c(NA, 'NA', 'Negative', NA)

library(dplyr)
data.frame(ID, COLLECTION_DT, TEST1, TEST2, TEST3) %>% 
group_by(ID, COLLECTION_DT) %>%
summarise_all(~first(na.omit(.)))
```

Giving

```
     ID COLLECTION_DT TEST1    TEST2    TEST3   
  <dbl> <date>        <fct>    <fct>    <fct>   
1     1 2016-07-01    Negative Positive Negative
2     2 2016-08-09    100      Negative NA
```

Comment: I have run into a new problem.  I ran your code on my dummy data that I provided and it worked like a charm.  I ran it on my actual data and I got this error      "Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Column `TEST1` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 0"  Any ideas what the problem could be?